# Asynchronous calls in ASP.net webforms stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, webforms

Stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Contributor_Search
    @fullname VARCHAR(60)
AS
    SELECT 
        C.id, years_of_experience, portfolio_link, specialization,
        notified_id, email, first_name, middle_name, last_name,
        birth_date, age 
    FROM 
        Contributor C 
    INNER JOIN 
        [User] U ON C.id = U.id
    WHERE 
        U.first_name + ' ' + U.middle_name + ' ' + U.last_name = @fullname

CREATE PROCEDURE Show_Original_Content
    @contributor_id INT
AS
    IF @contributor_id IS NULL
        SELECT * 
        FROM Original_Content OC 
        INNER JOIN Content C ON OC.id = C.id 
        INNER JOIN Contributor CO ON C.contributor_id = CO.id 
        WHERE OC.filter_status = 1
    ELSE
        SELECT * 
        FROM Original_Content OC 
        INNER JOIN Content C ON OC.id = C.id 
        INNER JOIN Contributor CO ON C.contributor_id = CO.id 
        WHERE OC.filter_status = 1 AND CO.id = @contributor_id
```

I want to run the first stored procedure if input is provided, and if not just jump into the second with null; if input is provided and it's ran however, I would like to get an ID using the first procedure and then use it in the second procedure, this is my current approach which unfortunately does not work.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionStr = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=iEgypt;";

    if(inputName.Value.Trim() != "")
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Contributor_Search";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (inputName.Value.Trim() != "")
            {
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@fullname", inputName.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
            else
            {
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@fullname", DBNull.Value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }

            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            id = rdr[0].ToString();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "Show_Original_Content";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (id != "")
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@contributor_id", inputName.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@contributor_id", DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        gvSearchResults.DataSource = rdr;
        gvSearchResults.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The `Read()` method of `SqlDataReader` must be called before accessing the rows in data reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, @vjgn suggests calling the `Read` method before accessing the rows in the `SqlDataReader`. For example:

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.Read())
{
    id = rdr[0].ToString();
}
```

That should work... Or alternatively you could use the `ExecuteScalar` method and not have to worry about opening the reader:

```
id = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString() ?? "";
```

The problem with that is now you are having to check for `null`, then converting it into an empty string. It is probably better to avoid converting to empty string and just check for both in your `if` statement.

```
id = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();

...

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
```

Another potential point of error is if the record has a null value in `first_name`, `middle_name`, or `last_name` then your search won't find any results because when you concatenate a null value with a non-null value, you get null. Try changing the where clause to the following:

```
isnull(U.first_name,'') + ' ' + isnull(U.middle_name,'') + ' ' + isnull(U.last_name,'') = @fullname
```

This looks like it does an **exact** search...

Comment: Worked and thanks for the improvements, much appreciated.